# My container-fluid Width drecreasing at xs devices on responsible mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbfdH.jpg)

OBS: I'm using ReactJS, the reason of 'className' instead 'class'

bootstrap 4.1

have a problem that I can not resolve it. From the sm breakpoint my container starts to decrease in width and does not complete 100% on xs devices, for example iphone5s or in responsive mode. I'm already using col-12. Thanks!

```
<div className='container-fluid'>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 bg-primary d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>
     <div><h2 className='nav nav-brand text-white'>LOGO</h2></div>
     <nav className='nav navbar d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>
     <div className='position-relative d-block d-sm-none d-none d-sm-block d-md-none'>
        <ul className='nav'>
          <li className='nav-item'><a href='#' className='nav-link'><img className='img-fluid' src={imgUiHaveNotifications} style={{width: '1em'}} /></a></li>
          <a href='#'><span className='badge badge-pill badge-danger position-absolute mt-3 shadow mb-5 rounded-circle' style={{top: -5, right: 78}}>5</span></a>
          <li className='nav-item '><a href='#' className='nav-link'><img className='rounded-circle' src={imgAvatar} style={{width: '1.5em'}} /><img src={imgMoreIcon} style={{width: 20}} /></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code that reproduces the issue

Comment: @Zim Updated my question with the code. Thank you!

Comment: This may not be the issue, but just an observation that 'className' should be changed to 'class'

Comment: @paddyfields  I'm using ReactJS which uses JSX syntax

Comment: I partially solved the problem by changing all units of measures of my items to 'em'. Some units were in Pixels, helping to break the layout.